# Autoselecting checklist items after I've selected a dropdown list item with a related primary key

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I need some help with the code in the under the ddlstore_selectedindexchange event. I'm trying to have the employee and customer checklist automatically check if their foreign key Id is equal to the stores primary key Id. I can't figure out what to put in the IF STATEMENT.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        using (StuffContainer context = new StuffContainer())
        {
            ddlstore.DataSource = context.Stores.ToList();
            ddlstore.DataTextField = "Name";
            ddlstore.DataValueField = "Id";
            ddlstore.DataBind();

            chkemp.DataSource = context.Customers.ToList();
            chkemp.DataTextField = "FName";
            chkemp.DataValueField = "Id";
            chkemp.DataBind();

            chkcust.DataSource = context.Employees.ToList();
            chkcust.DataTextField = "FName";
            chkcust.DataValueField = "Id";
        }
    }
}

protected void ddlstore_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int storeId = int.Parse(ddlstore.SelectedValue);

    using (StuffContainer context = new StuffContainer())
    {
        List<Employee> employees = context.Employees.ToList();

        var employee = context.Employees.Where(x => x.StoreId == storeId);

        foreach(Employee item in employees)
        {
           if()
           {

           }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
protected void ddlstore_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int storeId = int.Parse(ddlstore.SelectedValue);

    using (StuffContainer context = new StuffContainer())
    {
        var employees = context.Employees
           .Where(x => x.StoreId == storeId)
           .Select(x => x.Id).ToList();
        var customers = context.Customers
           .Where(x => x.StoreId == storeId)
           .Select(x => x.Id).ToList();

        foreach(ListItem item in chkemp.Items)
            item.Selected = employees.Contains(int.Parse(item.Value));

        foreach(ListItem item in chkcust.Items)
            item.Selected = customers.Contains(int.Parse(item.Value));
    }
}
```